# Как назначить исполняемый файл при запуске библиотеки классов на .net-6?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-6

Не смог найти свойство проекта, которое бы отвечало за запуск exe файла при запуске библиотеки, в моем случае это NanoCAD, проект на dotnet 6. В проектах на net framework просто указывается путь к исполняемому файлу в свойствах проекта, и он запускается после компиляции библиотеки. Как сделать то же самое для .net 6?

Comment: Тип проекта у Вас какой?

Comment: В настройках сборки это делается, я полагаю. Хотя непонятно, что вы имеете в виду, когда упоминаете компиляцию - просто сборку или публикацию?

Comment: Тип проекта - библиотека классов. Хотелось бы, чтобы при сборке открывался исполняемый файл, делал подобное для проекта на net framework, но properties проекта на core несколько отличаются, и не очень понятно, где указывать путь к исполняемому файлу.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.
Нужно в проекте создать файл `launchsettings.json` в папке `Properties`, где указать путь к исполняемому файлу в свойстве `executablePath`:

```
{
  "profiles": 
{
    "Профиль 1": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "path:\\.exe"
    }
  }
}
```